# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or

Tags: sql-server

my code:

```
create table customers
(
customer_id int not null identity primary key,
customer_fname char(50) not null,
customer_lname char(50) not null,
customer_CodeMeli int not null unique,
branch_code int not null,
total_debt int not null,
debt_month int not null,
number_paid int not null,
total_remaining int not null,
number_remaining int not null,
constraint fk_customers foreign key(branch_code) references branch(branch_code)
)

create table branch
(
branch_code int not null primary key identity,
branch_name char(50) not null unique,
total_remaining int not null,
)
create table kasr_bd
(
n_id int not null primary key identity,
n float
)
create procedure sp_updatekasr_bd  @n float 
as
begin
      insert into kasr_bd values (@n)
end
    create trigger kasr_bdupdate on kasr_bd after insert
    as
    begin
           update customers set total_remaining = total_remaining - (((select n from inserted) * total_remaining)/100)
           update branch set total_remaining = total_remaining - (((select n from inserted) * total_remaining)/100)       
    end

sp_updatekasr_bd 12
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your trigger is flawed, it assumes that an `INSERT` contains 1 row. [Bad Habits to Kick : Abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers)

Comment: this worked fine for me. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e7466261d4e6797e92a523827a11a171

Comment: You need to declare Top (1) in your select query like this "select Top 1 n from inserted".

Comment: Because there are no rows in `customers` or `branch` @SowmyadharGourishetty .

Comment: No, @PurveshSangani , that is **not** what the OP should be doing... They need to change to a set based solution... That "solution" can makes things worse, not better, as it conceals the real underlying problem.

Comment: What are your expected results here? What are you trying to achieve with this trigger? Should the trigger *really* be updating the value of ***every*** row? If so, then that seems like hyou have a design flaw, as repeating the same value on every row in a table infers it shouldn't be being stored in that table.

Comment: Your latest edit dosen't make any sense. You can't define a `TRIGGER` inside an Stored Procedure. Also, the `sp_` prefex is **reserved** by Microsoft and means **S**ecial **P**rodure; it should *not* be usef for User Stored Procedure. Doing so can cause your object to not work after an update and comes with performance issues. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: @Larnu No, I did not define it inside the procedure

Comment: @Larno Can you help more?

Comment: Receive n decimal number system from user and deduct n% from all customers from their remaining debt amount

This is what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question (as your approach is flawed) but you should consider an [indexed view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15) to calculate the remaining values from the header record and the sum of any line items.

This allows for better data integrity as you cannot fiddle the results from the view by disabling triggers or altering the value directly.

It also takes care of your set operations seamlessly in a way your trigger does not (but could).